# How to generate 24-bit RGB values "more gracefully"?

Tags: c, algorithm, rgb

**Source file:**

```
/* gcc <filename.c> -o <filename> -std=c99 -Wall */
   
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  unsigned int RGB[8];
  for (unsigned char Cnt = 1; Cnt < 8; Cnt++)
  {
    RGB[Cnt] =   ((unsigned int)((6+Cnt)/7)) * (((unsigned int) 0xFF) << (8*((9-Cnt)%3)))
               + ((unsigned int) (Cnt/4))    * (((unsigned int) 0xFF) << (8*((8-Cnt)%3)))
               + ((unsigned int) (Cnt/7))    *  ((unsigned int) 0xFF);
    fprintf (stdout, "%06X\n", RGB[Cnt]);
  }
}
```

**Output:** (order: R -> G -> B -> R+G -> G+B -> B+R -> R+G+B)

> FF0000
>
> 00FF00
>
> 0000FF
>
> FFFF00
>
> 00FFFF
>
> FF00FF
>
> FFFFFF

**I wonder...**

- whether there are any more graceful ways to generate 24-bit RGB values **in this order** as above?
- whether those type-castings are necessary **in ISO C99**?
- whether unsigned symbols in type-casting are necessary **in ISO C99** in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly a more graceful way is to just code the table with the hex values.  Any programmatic way - even an elegant one - of generating 7 numbers is going to be more obscure than the numbers themselves.

Comment: I'd just hardcode it. It'll be a lot easier to read and verify the correctness of a 7-element hex array literal.

Comment: If `int` is 32-bit (or more) then all of the casts are redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is just to hardcode values, it will be easy to read.

Anyway if you want to generate them - this variant is faster neither integer division:

```
unsigned int RGB[7];
unsigned int values[] = {0, 0xff};
unsigned int rgbmask = 0x1EBC54; // binary 111101011110001010100
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    RGB[i] = values[rgbmask>>2&1]<<16 | values[rgbmask>>1&1]<<8 | values[rgbmask&1];
    rgbmask >>= 3;
    printf ("%06X\n", RGB[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not what you wanted to see, but this seems so much better:

```
unsigned int RGB[8] = {
    0x000000,
    0xFF0000,
    0x00FF00,
    0x0000FF,
    0xFFFF00,
    0x00FFFF,
    0xFF00FF,
    0xFFFFFF
};
```

Comment: I agree that this is the best way, but I had to generate the number instead of hardcoding to avoid being hacked in the project.